# Accessing virtual hosts on the host OS from a guest OS in VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox, localhost, virtualhost

Through VirtualBox, I need to access the host's (Mac OS X 10.6) virtual hosts through guest OSs (Windows XP and 7).

I am able to access the `localhost` URL and can see the directory structure of the `~/Username/Sites` folder from the guest OSs via the local URL of the host, my Mac, in the guest's browser but get a 403 error when I try to go deeper into the file structure, for example, `mymacsname.lcoal/~Username/Sites` is accessible, but I get a `403` when I browse to `ymacsname.lcoal/~Username/Sites/somewebsite/`.

NB: I also get the `403` when I try to access `ymacsname.lcoal/~Username/Sites/somewebsite/` from my Mac's (host's) browser.

**Edit:**

I've checked the access logs on the host OS (the Mac) and strangely, if I browse to a directory without a `.htaccess` file I receive a `"HTTP/1.1" 200 1935` response and am able to either browser that directory's index or am served it's default Web page. If there is a `.htaccess` file in the directory I receive a `"HTTP/1.1 403 247"` response!

This narrows a lot of the problem down to the `.htaccess` file, so I'll continue to research on this, I'm really grateful for your help!

**Re-Edit**

Going further, it would seem to be an issue with my `.htaccess`'s `mod_rewrite` rules. I've included my `.htaccess` code below, it would seem, like it should, that it's redirecting the browser to `/Users/Jay/Sites/chassis/library/bootstrap.php` but it would seem I don't have privileges to access that file (`bootstrap.php`).

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/public/index.html !-f
RewriteRule ^$ library/bootstrap.php [L]

RewriteRule ^$ public/index.html [L]

RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9/-]+)$ library/bootstrap.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Getting so close! Please help me solve this!

**Re-Re-Edit**

In case this helps, here is a clip from my main Apache configuration file (`/private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf`):

```
<Directory />
Options FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride None
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was definitely a permissions problem.

**Solved** by adding:

```
<Directory />
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

to `/private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf`.

I also needed to edit the hosts file on the guest OSs (Windows XP and 7) like so:

```
192.168.123.123 somevhost
192.168.123.123 someothervhost.dev
```

Where the IP address stated is that of the host OS and `somevhost`… is the name of the virtual host on the host OS.

I needed to set the host OS to use a static IP, as if it were assigned by DHCP, you'd have to edit the host file on the guest OS each time your host OS's IP changed.

These Web sites really helped:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/972034#LetMeFixItMyselfAlways

http://mark-kirby.co.uk/2008/setting-up-virtual-hosts-on-os-x-leopard/

http://adactio.com/journal/1395

Answer (score 1):

You might want to start by checking the access logs of the web server to see what is actually being passed onto it - both successes vs. failures.